# Javascript Flask URL_for improper redirect

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I know there are already several questions about the best way to do a Flask URL_for through Javascript, but I can't get it to work for me. I am new to Front End development so go easy on me here. I have tried multiple ways, and each way returns an error or a different problem.

I have a Bootstrap dropdown menu that when clicked on, should return a report to the user. I thought I had it solved earlier because I can get it to return the report if I do it this way:

```
$('.dropdown-item').on('click', function (event) {
            branch = $(this).attr('branch');
            selected_date = selected_date;
            window.location.href = route_summ/branch/selected_date
```

The problem is then that it adds the route_summ in front of every other file, including javascript, css, etc files, so none of those can be found any longer. If instead I do:

```
window.location.href = "{{url_for('route_summ', branch=branch, selected_date = selected_date)}}"
```

As I have seen in other posts people suggest, it doesn't look at any of the variables and instead just tries going to route_summ//.

Some posts talk about using an $.ajax call, so I have done it this way:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: "/route_summ/" + $(this).attr('branch') + '/' + selected_date,
  data: {
    branch: $(this).attr('branch')
  },
  method: 'GET',
  success: function(response) {

    console.log('Success');

    window.location.href = "{{url_for('route_summ', branch = branch, selected_date = selected_date)}}"
  }
});
```

But that doesn't work either. It establishes a call and returns "Success", but it doesn't redirect to the site. If I were to just go to the site, it works, but I can't get it to link to it without screwing up the other dependent links on it. Can anyone please help me? I'm at my wit's end here.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out. My first solution would've worked, but I needed to put a "url_for" in my  tags. I'm going to leave this up in case any other novices run into this problem.